# Checking For SSL With PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ssl

I need to force my web application to only work over HTTPS, now ordinarily I would check for the existence of the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` value however due to the fact that I use AWS Certificate Manager for issuing and managing my SSL certificate and the application is behind an AWS Load Balancer which terminates the SSL at the LB and sends it on internally using normal HTTP the server is not populating that value.

What I am looking for is a way to detect if the connection is being made over HTTP or HTTPS taking into account the fact that the SSL certificate is on the load balancer and terminates there.

Comment: Could someone explain why there are two close votes for my question. I have asked a specific question that can be answered with a specific answer.

Comment: Different people have different views on what questions are exactly suitable for SO. That's life. Move on. (Btw I did not cast a close vote)

Comment: I think this is a real life answer in some special cases and environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check the X-Forwarded-Proto header.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

> a de facto standard for identifying the originating protocol of an HTTP request, since a reverse proxy (or a load balancer) may communicate with a web server using HTTP even if the request to the reverse proxy is HTTPS. An alternative form of the header (X-ProxyUser-Ip) is used by Google clients talking to Google servers.

X-Forwarded-Proto: https

With PHP you can check this with:

`apache_response_headers();`

http://php.net/manual/de/function.apache-response-headers.php

Comment: I wonder why Martijn deleted your 1st answer...

Comment: I believe my first answer was a little bit to brief

Comment: I understand a downvote, but not removal. Anyway, it does not really matter. Plus 1 from me btw.

Comment: Maybe he knows a better way. That's why i upvoted the question. I need that answer too.